# How to have a datatype of type <ClassObject, List<ClassObject2>>?

Tags: c#, collections

How would I make a datatype similar to Dictionary where I could have something like:

```
Dictionary<ClassObject1, List<ClassObject2>> stuff;
```

Basically, I have `ClassOject1` with an unknown number of objects of type `ClassObject2` that belong to `ClassObject1`. Would I just use type `dynamic` or something?

Edit: Trying the following code:

```
Dictionary<VisitorInfoCookie, List<VisitorInfoCookieValue>> stuff = new List<VisitorInfoCookieValue>>();
```

causes the compiler to say `A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type` with an angry red squiggly under `()`

Comment: So you want a dictionary, but you don't want a dictionary?

Comment: I tried using a dictionary but the compiler isn't happy with it so I honestly don't know what kind of datatype I need.

Comment: can you show classobject1 and classobject2?

Comment: Please show what you tried with the `Dictionary`.  It should work fine.

Comment: They're aggregate classes. Specifically, they contain cookies from the Request and Response objects appropriately named `Cookies` and `CookieValues`. Since we can have multiple values per cookie, I kind of need to track which values belong to which cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating dictionary.your code should be like.

```
Dictionary<VisitorInfoCookie, List<VisitorInfoCookieValue>> stuff = new Dictionary<VisitorInfoCookie, List<VisitorInfoCookieValue>>();
```

if you want to add items to dictionary you can directly do this.

```
Dictionary<VisitorInfoCookie, List<VisitorInfoCookieValue>> stuff = new Dictionary<VisitorInfoCookie, List<VisitorInfoCookieValue>>
{
     {visitorInfoCookie1 , visitorInfoCookieValues1},
     {visitorInfoCookie2 , visitorInfoCookieValues2},
     //...
};
```

Comment: Oh my god. I can't believe... ugh. Maybe it's time to stop coding for the day. Man, thank you.(I feel stupid now).